# How can I create a table if not exist on Flask with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and I have the following code:

Model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'task', 'useexisting': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    firstname = Column(String)
```

.env

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```

app.py

```
def create_app(config_file):
    """Create a Flask application using the app factory pattern."""

    app = Flask(__name__)

    """Load configuration."""

    app.config.from_pyfile(config_file)

    """Init app extensions."""
    from .extensions import db

    db.init_app(app)
```

This creates the SQLite file if it does not exist, but not the tables of each model.

The question is what can I do in order to create the tables for each model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add:

```
db.create_all()
```

in `app.py` at the end of `create_app()`.

`create_all()` will create the tables only when they don't exist and would not change the tables created before.

If you want to create the database and the tables from the command line you can just type:

```
python
from app.py import db
db.create_all()
exit()
```

The working example:

```python
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Secret key"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///my_database.sqlite3"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(50))

db.create_all()

# add a row
# comment out after the 1st run
table_row = Data(name="My Name", email="myemail@mail.com", phone="123456")
db.session.add(table_row)
db.session.commit()
print "A row was added to the table"

# read the data
row = Data.query.filter_by(name="My Name").first()
print "Found:", row.email, row.phone

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is for Python 2.7, to run with Python 3.x just change the the `print` statements to call the `print()` function.

**NOTE:**
When using **automatic** model class constructor the arguments passed to model class constructor **must** be `keyword` arguments or there will be an error. Otherwise you can override the `__init__()` inside `Data()` class like this:

```python
def __init__(self, name, email, phone, **kwargs):
    super(Data, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.phone = phone
```

In that case you don't have to use `keyword` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you need first to use `Shell Context Processor` to load **automatically** all Model objects

in `app.py` add

```
# import all models from all blueprints you have
from .users.models import User


@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return { 'db': db, 'User': User .. }
```

and then use `Flask shell` command

```
(venv) $ flask shell
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine=sqlite:///data-dev.sqlite> # something similar to that
>>> 
>>> User
<class 'api.users.models.User'>
>>> 
>>> # to create database if not exists and all tables, run the command below
>>> db.create_all()
```

maybe you'll need `Flask-Migrate` for advanced operations (migrations) on your database: create new table, update tables / fields ...

Comment: OP wanted to know how to create the tables **from within** `app.py` and not by using the command line.

Comment: @Chupo_cro database should be created for **once**, so if you put `db.create_all()` in the app factory `create_app()` you are about loosing your data each time you relaunch or restart server or calling `flask run` because the database will be re-created each time, so the better way is to use **Shell Context Processor** or better a **command**

Comment: `db.create_all()` will, as I said in the answer, **not** change or delete the tables created before but will only create tables which don't exist. You can run `db.create_all()` as many times as you want, if the tables already exist it will do nothing.

Comment: yes, you're right, according to the doc : **Conditional by default**, will not attempt to recreate tables already present in the target database, `create_all(bind=None, tables=None, checkfirst=True)` -  `checkfirst` – Defaults to `True`, don’t issue CREATEs for tables already present in the target database.